# Printing objects from a list which is a value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble rewriting the non-commented code to code that uses LINQ methods such as `.Select`, `.Where` etc, basically like the commented bit I've provided.

I had the idea of using `String.Join(", ", ...)` instead of a `StringBuilder`.

```
private Dictionary<Int32, List<Ticket>> desks;

public void printTicketsByDesk(DateTime from, DateTime to) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfDesks; i++) 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Ticket ticket in desks[i]) 
        {
            if (boughtBetween(ticket, from, to)) 
            {
                sb.AppendLine(ticket.ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    /*
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Enumerable.Range(0, numOfDesks)
        .SelectMany(i => desks[i])
        .Where(ticket => boughtBetween(ticket, from, to))
        .Select(ticket => sb.AppendLine(ticket.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    */
}
```

Comment: So are you looking for help on re-writing it without using LINQ?

Comment: i think its the other way round, rewriting code to use LINQ - cos , u know, LINQ is cool

Comment: The non-commented code is better. LINQ is primarily for querying, but because it iterates over collections people often try to use it in place of a `for` or `foreach` loop. The uncommented code is much easier to read. Someone could figure out the LINQ code but it would take just a little longer. It's not worth it.

Comment: especially bad idea where the lambdas have side effects (sb.Append,...)

Comment: Where is `numOfDesks` defined?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", desks.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Where(ticket => BoughtBetween(ticket, from, to)))));`

Comment: @RufusL and OP note that the orginal code outputs one line per desk. These 2 replacement pieces of code output one single line

Comment: @pm100 Yeah, I was going off his statement, *" had the idea of using `String.Join(", ", ...)` instead of a `StringBuilder`."*

Comment: @pm100 I spent a few minutes trying to write an understandable LINQ chain to do this and prove you wrong, took a breather, came back and didn't understand what I just wrote, and conceded that you're right.

Comment: @jdphenix :-) BTW - I am a huge fan of linq, in its place. This is not its place

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is primarily for querying - (the "Q" stands for Query) but because it works with collections there's a tendency to try to use it in place of `foreach` loops.

This is compounded by the `List<T>` `.ForEach` extension which isn't actually LINQ but sort of looks like it.

If you're looping through something simple you may not need to use LINQ at all. Your original code is perfectly readable.

When we do use LINQ it's for querying one or more collections to create the `IEnumerable` that we're going to iterate over. But even then it's good to break it up into smaller pieces that are easier to read. There's a tendency - I have been guilty - to write long, complicated LINQ queries because it looks (or looked) cool.

This isn't too bad:

```
var tickets = desks.SelectMany(desk=>desk);
    .Where(ticket => boughtBetween(ticket, from, to));
```

but it doesn't hurt to break it up:

```
var tickets = desks.SelectMany(desk=>desk);
var ticketsInDateRange = tickets.Where(ticket => boughtBetween(ticket, from, to));
```

Then, having defined the collection, you can iterate over it with a normal `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var ticket in ticketsInDateRange)
{
    // append to stringbuilder or print
}
```

There's not much point in appending lines to a `StringBuilder` if you're just going to print the lines. You could just `Console.Write` each line one at a time. `StringBuilder` is useful if you actually need to build a string and you don't want to inefficiently create one new string after another by concatenating onto the previous string.

Comment: i would have stuck with your implicit original message. 'The existing code works (we assume) and is clear, why would you create obscure LINQ code'

Comment: @pm100 True, I'll add a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it an unordered dictionary, if not an list/array? If it was ordered, it would make things a lot easier. If you *must* have a dictionary, consider using a `SortedDictionary<,>` instead. (but you still use a sequential range of keys anyway...)

Considering you're doing separate calls to output the contents of each desk, you won't be able to do this in one query, you'll need some loop.

```
foreach (var kvp in desks.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
{
    var lines =
        from ticket in kvp.Value
        where boughtBetween(ticket, from, to)
        select ticket.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
}
```

Comment: note that this outputs one line. The original code outputs one line per desk. I know the one writeline has newlines inserted, but is not the same, and if this was a call to a logging service for example it would make a huge difference

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. But they're not on one line, but yeah, if it was buffered, those extra calls to `Console.WriteLine` might make a difference (though in this case, not likely).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to write out all the `Ticket` items that were purchased between two dates. Its not clear from your sample where `numDates` is set, so I'm assuming it's the count of all items in the dictionary.

You also mentioned that you want to use `String.Join(", ", ...)` instead of a `StringBuilder`.

If these assumptions are true, then you can do this by calling `SelectMany` on the dictionary values (which are `List<Ticket>` types, represented by `value` below) that, when passed to `BoughtBetween`, return true.

Though this may not be super easy to read, you can do it in one line:

```
public static void PrintTicketsByDesk(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", desks.Values.SelectMany(value => 
        value.Where(ticket => BoughtBetween(ticket, from, to)))));
}
```

If you instead wanted to output them each on a separate line, you could replace `", "` with `Environment.NewLine`.

---

For completeness, here is the related class and method:

```
class Ticket
{
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PurchaseDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
}

public static bool BoughtBetween(Ticket ticket, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    return ticket?.PurchaseDate >= from && ticket.PurchaseDate <= to;
}
```